# How to set a backing list for a ListEditor

Tags: gwt

how already stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752934/how-to-connect-gwt-listeditor-and-leafvalueeditor) i am currently trying to get into gwt editors.
I figured i was missing a backing list to hold the data i manipulate.
I tried to assign that backing list with a setValue call from the parent view. Now the compiler complains it is missing the getter for groupList. 
I understand that by convention the groupList property is derived by naming the Editor groupListEditor. What would be the right way to attach the lists? It seems i need to somehow call setValue with a list or else it does not seem to work. What would be the right way to do it?

My Editor looks like this:

```
public class GroupListEditor extends Composite implements
        IsEditor<ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor>> {

    private static StringListEditorUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(StringListEditorUiBinder.class);

    interface StringListEditorUiBinder extends
            UiBinder<Widget, GroupListEditor> {
    }

    @UiField
    FlowPanel pWidget;

    @UiField
    PushButton bAdd;

    @UiField
    FlowPanel pList;


    private class StringItemEditorSource extends EditorSource<GroupItemEditor> {
        @Override
        public GroupItemEditor create(final int index) {
            GroupItemEditor subEditor = new GroupItemEditor();
            pList.insert(subEditor, index);
            subEditor
                    .addDeleteHandler(new EditorDeleteEvent.EditorDeleteHandler() {
                        public void onEditorDeleteEvent(EditorDeleteEvent event) {
                            remove(index);
                        }
                    });
            return subEditor;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(GroupItemEditor subEditor) {
            subEditor.removeFromParent();
        }

        @Override
        public void setIndex(GroupItemEditor editor, int index) {
            pList.insert(editor, index);
        }
    }

    private ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor> editor = ListEditor
            .of(new StringItemEditorSource());



    public GroupListEditor() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }


    @UiHandler("bAdd")
    void onBAddClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Log.debug("Add button clicked");
        add();
    }

    private void add() {
        String s = "";
        //TODO: Problem is there is no backing list, FIx this
        editor.getList().add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    private void remove(final int index) {
        editor.getList().remove(index);
    }

}
```

The Editor is used as a sub-editor in a editor widget like this:
I tried to set the backing list:

```
public class ContainerEditorDialogPresenterWidget extends PresenterWidget<ContainerEditorDialogPresenterWidget.MyView> implements
                ContainerEditorDialogUiHandlers {


    private final PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    ContainerEditorDialogPresenterWidget(EventBus eventBus,
                               MyView view, PlaceManager placeManager) {
        super(eventBus, view);
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
    }
    /**
     * {@link LocalDialogPresenterWidget}'s PopupView.
     */
    public interface MyView extends PopupView, ContainerEditView<ContainerDto>, HasUiHandlers<ContainerEditorDialogUiHandlers> {
    }

    private ContainerDto currentContainerDTO = null;
    private DeviceDto currentDeviceDTO = null;
    private final EventBus eventBus;

    private SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ContainerDto, ?> driver;

    public ContainerDto getCurrentContainerDTO() {
        return currentContainerDTO;
    }

    public void setCurrentContainerDTO(ContainerDto currentContainerDTO) {
        this.currentContainerDTO = currentContainerDTO;
    }

    public void setCurrentDeviceDTO(DeviceDto currentDeviceDTO) {
        this.currentDeviceDTO = currentDeviceDTO;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
        driver.edit(currentContainerDTO); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        driver = getView().createEditorDriver();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateContainer() {
        ContainerDto dev = driver.flush();
        eventBus.fireEvent(new ContainerUpdatedEvent(dev));
    }

}
```

I tried to assign the backing list (just an empty string list) in the view:

```
public class ContainerEditorDialogView extends
        PopupViewWithUiHandlers<ContainerEditorDialogUiHandlers> implements
        ContainerEditorDialogPresenterWidget.MyView, Editor<ContainerDto> {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<PopupPanel, ContainerEditorDialogView> {
    }
    public interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ContainerDto, ContainerEditorDialogView> {
    }

    @UiField
    TextBox uuid;   
    @UiField
    TextBox name;   
    @UiField
    TextBox groups;
    //@UiField
    //TextBox device;
    //public TextBox getDevice() {
    //  return device;
    //}
    @UiField     
    GroupListEditor groupListEditor;
    @UiField
    TextBox imei;   
    @UiField
    TextBox type;   
    @UiField
    TextBox user;   
    @UiField
    Button okButton;
    @UiField
    Button cancelButton;


    @Inject
    ContainerEditorDialogView(Binder uiBinder, EventBus eventBus) {
        super(eventBus);

        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor> ed = null;
        groupListEditor.asEditor().setValue(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ContainerDto, ?> createEditorDriver() {
        Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
        driver.initialize(this);
        return driver;
    }

    //Should this handled by a presenter?
    @UiHandler("okButton")
    void okButtonClicked(ClickEvent event) {

        getUiHandlers().updateContainer();

        hide();
    }

    @UiHandler("cancelButton")
    void cancelButtonClicked(ClickEvent event) {

        hide();
    }

}
```

Thank you!

**Update:**
A version of the GroupListEditor without a separate ArrayList would look like this and is what i started with:

```
public class GroupListEditor extends Composite implements
        IsEditor<ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor>> {

    private static StringListEditorUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(StringListEditorUiBinder.class);

    interface StringListEditorUiBinder extends
            UiBinder<Widget, GroupListEditor> {
    }

    @UiField
    FlowPanel pWidget;

    @UiField
    PushButton bAdd;

    @UiField
    FlowPanel pList;

    private class StringItemEditorSource extends EditorSource<GroupItemEditor> {
        @Override
        public GroupItemEditor create(final int index) {
            GroupItemEditor subEditor = new GroupItemEditor();
            pList.insert(subEditor, index);
            subEditor
                    .addDeleteHandler(new EditorDeleteEvent.EditorDeleteHandler() {
                        public void onEditorDeleteEvent(EditorDeleteEvent event) {
                            remove(index);
                        }
                    });
            return subEditor;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(GroupItemEditor subEditor) {
            subEditor.removeFromParent();
        }

        @Override
        public void setIndex(GroupItemEditor editor, int index) {
            pList.insert(editor, index);
        }
    }

    private ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor> editor = ListEditor
            .of(new StringItemEditorSource());



    public GroupListEditor() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }


    @UiHandler("bAdd")
    void onBAddClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Log.debug("Add button clicked");
        add();
    }

    private void add() {
        String s = "Stuff";
        editor.getList().add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    private void remove(final int index) {
        editor.getList().remove(index);
    }

}
```

Since i declare the Editor as

```
@UiField     
GroupListEditor groupListEditor;
```

Should the required getter of ContainerDto not be named getGroupList() ?
You refer to DeviceDto, which is just carried around and should not interfere with the editor. 
Since the GroupListEditor implements

```
IsEditor<ListEditor<String, GroupItemEditor>>
```

it should expect a List, right?
My ContainerDto has the field

```
protected ArrayList<String> groupList;
```

So that should be fine, i guess. This was my starting point before trying to manually call setValue. 
When i that, i get this error, when clicking the "Add" button.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at 
testproject.client.application.containers.editor.GroupListEditor.add(GroupListEditor.java:81)
at testproject.client.application.containers.editor.GroupListEditor.onBAddClick(GroupListEditor.java:76)
```

which refers to `editor.getList().add(s)` which means there is no list...

**Update 2:**
I changed the declaration of the UIField to:

```
@UiField
@Path("groupList")
GroupListEditor groupListEditor;
```

But i still get the NullPointerException when trying to add stuff to the list like before: `editor.getList().add(s);`

Comment: No, if your `ContainerDTO` has a getter called `getGroupList()` then your `GroupListEditor` must be called `groupList` too. Or you add a `Path` declarion to point it to the correct `getter` (see my reply below)

Comment: did you make sure that your `groupList` is initialized to an empty `ArrayList`  (see upadte below) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to manually call `setList` to pass the list to your `SubEditor`. That should be taken care of for you by the parent/container Editor.

However the Editor will use the `UiField` name to match the corresponding `getter` in your backing DTO.

In your above example this will only work if your `DeviceDTO` has a `getGroupListEditor()` getter that returns the type that your `ListEditor` expects (beacuse of `@UiField GroupListEditor groupListEditor;`).

If your `DeviceDTO` doesn't contain the corresponding getter you can do 3 things:

1. Rename your `@UiField GroupListEditor groupListEditor;` (i.e. `groupItems`)
2. Rename the `getter` in your `DeviceDTO` to `getGroupListEditor`
3. add `Path('groupItems')` to your `@UiField GroupListEditor groupListEditor;`

Solution 3 is usually the way to go:

```
@UiField     
@Path('groupItems')
GroupListEditor groupListEditor;
```

Note: Change `groupItems` has to match the `getter` in your `DeviceDTO` that returns the group items.

**Update:**

This is how your `DeviceDTO` looks like and how you use `Path` to point your editor to the correct `getter`. As long as your `groupList` class variable is initialized to an empty ArrayList everything should work fine.

```
class DeviceDTO {
  protected List<String> groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
  public List<String> getGroupList() {
      return groupList;
  }
}

public class ContainerEditorDialogView extends
    PopupViewWithUiHandlers<ContainerEditorDialogUiHandlers> implements
    ContainerEditorDialogPresenterWidget.MyView, Editor<ContainerDto> {

    ....
    @UiField     
    @Path("groupList")
    GroupListEditor groupListEditor;     
}
```

Comment: I edited my question above for a more complex reply.

Comment: The only thing i did different: I declared the groupList as ArrayList and not as List. May that be the answer? Now it works. Thank you very much. That really helped me!